# Can we do intl-tel-input without any jquery plugins?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intl-tel-input

with `intl-tel-input` we can validate international phone numbers,but it has jquery dependency,   is their any other replica of `intl-tel-input` without `jquery` dependency?
[githubCode](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#demo-and-examples)